# I don't know why this is answer. $f\left( x\right) =\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }f_{n}\left( x\right) =0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

"n" is positive integer.  An interval is [0,3].
$$f_{n}\left( x\right) =\begin{cases}n^{2}x\left( 0\leq x\leq \dfrac {1}{n}\right) \\ n\left( 2-nx\right) \left( \dfrac {1}{n} <x\leq \dfrac {2}{n}\right) \\ 0\left( \dfrac {2}{n} <x\leq 3\right) \end{cases}$$

I want to calculate the following formula.
$$f\left( x\right) =\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }f_{n}\left( x\right)$$
So I don't know, I researched. And then, this answer is the following.
$$f\left( x\right) =\lim _{n\rightarrow +\infty }f_{n}\left( x\right) =0$$
I don't know why this is answer. Please tell me.

Comment: If $x=0$, then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $x>0$, then can you find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $x \leq \frac{2}{N}$?

Comment: Can you show when you are stuck in your derivations? Because it looks rather straightforward if you do this by the definition of the limit.

Comment: For any given $x>0$ and $n>\dfrac{2}{x}$ what is the value of $f_n(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky at the beginning. The key idea here is that the interval $\left(\frac 2n, 3\right]$ **grows monotonically** as $n\to\infty$ and will eventually, include all the points inside $\left(0,3\right]$. Notice how $0$ will never be included (no matter how big $n$ is).

With that in mind, if you fix an $x$, then it's clear from the function definition that, after a certain $n_0$, $f_n(x) = 0$ for each $n\ge n_0$.

In particular, this is an example of pointwise but not uniform convergence (because $f_n(0)$ diverges).